# PostgreSQL: How to restrict resources per DB, Schema or User

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

Is there a way to configure PostgreSQL server instance to limit resources, e.g. work_mem or max_parallel_workers, by databases or schema? (or even limit a specific user)

To my knowledge, parameters from postgresql.conf affect the entire postmaster instance.

Background of this question is multi-tenancy based on DB schema and resource isolation.

Comment: There are some (limited) ways to do this using Linux control groups. There is an extension to support that: https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_cgroups

Comment: Virtualization springs to mind. One host, multiple (virtual) linux servers, one PostgreSQL instance per server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set many parameters on the database or user level with

```
ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...;
ALTER ROLE ... SET ...;
```

Connection limits can also be set on that level.

But a lot of things are global to the cluster (like `shared_buffers`), and a lot of resources (like CPU and I/O) cannot be limited at all.

I second the horse's comment to look at [`pg_cgroups`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_cgroups), but I should mention that I am the author. That doesn't work on a database or user level though, but if you want to separate databases, it is always commendable to put them in different clusters anyway.